# Select minimum from maximums of groups

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table billa which have columns: currency, amount and billed_at.

I would like to fetch minimum billed_at from maximums of billed_at of each currency

Fetching maximum billed_at for each currency can be done with this query

```
SELECT MAX(billed_at), currency FROM bills GROUP BY currency
```

For example it returned 2 rows

> 2013-12-16 13:31:18 UTC, "EUR"
>
> 2013-12-02 14:57:00 UTC, "USD"

Then I need to fetch minimum billed_at from this results. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `select billed_at,currency from bills order by billed_at limit 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shuld use your query as subquery in from clause as blow

```
select min(billed_at)
from (SELECT MAX(billed_at), currency FROM bills GROUP BY currency) AS Tab
```

Comment: Er, surely ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1 !?!?

Comment: @Strawberry It's another solution :) You can include it as an answer.

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks for reply, but it will choose right row with billed_at and currency, but I need billed_at value only. But anyway, thanks!

Comment: Well, not if you don't select currency ! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MIN(billed_at_max) 
FROM (SELECT MAX(billed_at)billed_at_max FROM bills GROUP BY currency)x
```

Comment: You forget currency field